# Unable to fill UIBezier at CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I would like to add several points to the custom made view, make a path, close it and fill with the color. In for loop, I place horizontally several thousand points and connect them with lines. However, I am not able to draw the close bezier path. What is the problem?

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight/2)];
 [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight/2)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight/2)];

for (int i=0; i<=screenWidth; i+=screenWidth/stepNo) {
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i, screenHeight/2)];
}
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight/2)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight)];

[path closePath];


//Create a CAShapeLayer that uses that UIBezierPath:
CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shape.path = path.CGPath;
shape.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:20/255.0 blue:147/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;

// 5
[self.view.layer addSublayer:shape];
```

Comment: Maybe you can try setting a backgroundColor on your layer to make sure it is displayed with the frame you expect.

Comment: My sublayer is displayed because if I use the construction (instead of for-loop) [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight/2)]; I can see the rectangular.

Comment: Then can you try constructing your path this way : `UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight/2)]; [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight)]; [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)]; [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(screenWidth, screenHeight/2)]; [path closePath];`

Comment: I have tried this construction and everything is displayaed correctly. However, I have more than 4 points that's why I need for loop.

Comment: How is `stepNo` defined?

Comment: It is just a constant, say its value is 1000.

Comment: Make sure you construct a path that really has a correct dimension because the code you shared constructs a path that is not visible. Give your parh a stroke color and you should see what you have traced and this will help you figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: Question why do you have this line twice `[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, screenHeight/2)];` or at all.